# Shall we try and clean the close vote review queue to start the new year?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

### Another update

We only have about 26 questions to review!

### Update

Due to hard work of several ask ubuntu community members and a mod or two we have now reduced the queue considerably. We are **almost there**!

---

### Original Post

- Shall we try and get rid of the close vote queue to start the new year?

For quite a while it has been around 200-300 items that are left to review. Are there a few of us that want to invest some time this week to try and get it cleaned up?

**TL;DR**: We need more reviewers for close questions (apart from the ones already doing a good job).

## Rationale

Given that 5 close votes are needed per question we need a 1000 votes in total. A rato of 20 votes per person per day we need the following number of people in the specified number of days to get rid of the persistent queue.

```
50 people in 1 day
25 people in 2 days
17 people in 3 days
13 people in 4 days
10 people in 5 days
8 people in 6 days
7 people in 7 days
6 people in 8 days
6 people in 9 days
5 people in 10 days
5 people in 11 days
4 people in 12 days
4 people in 13 days
4 people in 14 days
3 people in 15 days
3 people in 16 days
3 people in 17 days
3 people in 18 days
3 people in 19 days
3 people in 20 days
2 people in 21 days
2 people in 22 days
2 people in 23 days
2 people in 24 days
2 people in 25 days
2 people in 26 days
2 people in 27 days
2 people in 28 days
2 people in 29 days  
2 people in 30 days
2 people in 31 days
2 people in 32 days
2 people in 33 days
1 person in 34 days
1 person in 35 days
```

- We also need many different people so we can easily skip questions we do not feel confident about.
- This does not take into account the new votes that come in every day.
- Maybe the most feasible option is to find ten people that want to jump in for five days (already doing this: Seth, Eric, Alvar, Braiam). So we'll need five more people (as I'll do my 20 a day as well).

## More information

To actually get the counter to zero we need to take into account the number of questions that get flagged for closing every day. In the following calculation I assume there are about 25 questions added to the queue every day. This affects the above count as follows:

```
56 people in 1 day
31 people in 2 days
23 people in 3 days
19 people in 4 days
16 people in 5 days
15 people in 6 days
13 people in 7 days
13 people in 8 days
12 people in 9 days
11 people in 10 days
11 people in 11 days
10 people in 12 days
10 people in 13 days
10 people in 14 days
10 people in 15 days
9 people in 16 days
9 people in 17 days
9 people in 18 days
9 people in 19 days
9 people in 20 days
9 people in 21 days
9 people in 22 days
8 people in 23 days
8 people in 24 days
8 people in 25 days
8 people in 26 days
8 people in 27 days
8 people in 28 days
8 people in 29 days
8 people in 30 days
8 people in 31 days
8 people in 32 days
8 people in 33 days
8 people in 34 days
8 people in 35 days
```

## Counting python script

```
total_votes_needed = 1000
max_votes_per_person = 20
x = 1.0
while x < 36:
    # the 125 is a guess for the amount of new votes needed every day (25 flagged questions * 5 votes needed)
    print int(round((total_votes_needed + 125 * x) / (x * max_votes_per_person ))), 'people in', int(x), 'days'
    x += 1
```

- obviously moderators could speed this up
- the ideal would be to have 8 people casting 20 votes every day.
- allowing fewer people to do more votes would also speed this up
- reducing the number of votes needed to 4 would work, or, even better, use the total reputation of the reviewers as an indication.
- the 25 new flagged questions/a day rate is made up. If someone could get an actual average using an SQL query that would be nice.

Comment: I for one will try and do my 20 every day :)

Comment: .I did mines :P

Comment: I would, but I have less than 2K rep :( I'm trying!

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Even worse that you need 3K for that queue. (Less than 250 users have that much rep on AU.)

Comment: Bleh. That's annoying.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness You have been doing some excellent flagging lately so just keep up that work. A good flag makes it so much easier to close a question.

Comment: 224 questions here on AU, that is doable. On SO, there are 99.9k...

Comment: @Lekensteyn Absolutely agree. The 99.9k on SO show a flaw in the system. Reviewing should be audited and make people gain minor reputation.

Comment: @don.joey Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to allow certain users in to the queue (for example, to take care of something like this...) even if they don't have 3K rep? Or could they drop it some to like 2K-2.5K? I want to help keep this site going, but getting 3K will take forever.

Comment: Under 100. Nice job guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## We are so close now!

From my perspective:

[image]

Many thanks to several highly regular close vote reviewers (I do not consider myself to be part of them)! Special mention to Eric, Seth, Radu, Braiam, Warren, minerz and Florian. Thanks also to jrg for helping us out big time a few days ago! Feel free to add those I forget to the queue.

## Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is our review queue right now:

[image]

As you can see, [only 222 items](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/152876/questions-by-number-of-close-votes), the ones that has close votes are 144:

[image]

(please, don't ask why there's a question with 5 close votes...)

This means that we need 17 + (12 * 2) + (36 * 3) + (76 *4) + (78*5) = 843 votes. We need 35 users in a single day to clear the queue. Sadly we don't have that amount of active users, but it's nice that people know that the review queue could be cleared fast (that if all the questions are to be closed).

Comment: We have 9 moderators though, between, lets say 8 active close voters, and 9 moderators we *should* have this thing cleared in a week.

Comment: @Seth - as you well know - Mods vote is binding - so in theory I could wrap up the whole queue in minutes without thinking.  As a great believer of community moderation, I would prefer to help out only as the last of the 5 votes to close rather than the lead closer.

Comment: @fossfreedom but if you see something blantatly off-topic, I hope mods will close it, right (*gets hopes up*)

Comment: @fossfreedom As I've told another mod recently, the Community isn't being very effective at moderating right now. I have nothing wrong with questions in the queue, but we just have too many right now. We're drowning (or at least getting there). No one would complain about a little help from you guys once in a while (queue wise that is, I know you're helping elsewhere).