# Clearing out the close review queue 2015

Tags: discussion, review

From my point of view, there are ~880 questions in the close review queue. I don't recall a time when it was below 700 (I became active only around last June).

Do we need to put in a concerted effort to clear it out?

One suggestion I have is to:

- gather a group of at least 10 people who can review,
- create a chatroom
- post questions which need at most 2 votes to close in that chatroom
- and hopefully there will be two users on hand to lend votes
- similarly for any post you encounter with 3+ close votes on it

This way, questions which are close to being closed will get cleared up much more quickly. Of course, it goes without saying that reviewers shouldn't blindly cast votes.

Anyone up for this? Or any other ways we can clear it out?

Related:

- [Should we be able to review 40 close votes when the queue length is less than 1000?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11510/should-we-be-able-to-review-40-close-votes-when-the-queue-length-is-less-than-10)
- [Do we need a event to clear out the Close Queue?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8603/do-we-need-a-event-to-clear-out-the-close-queue)
- [Shall we try and clean the close vote review queue to start the new year?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7929/shall-we-try-and-clean-the-close-vote-review-queue-to-start-the-new-year)
- [How to know which questions should be closed, a reprise](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11703/how-to-know-which-questions-should-be-closed-a-reprise)

Comment: Also related: [How to know which questions should be closed, a reprise](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11703/how-to-know-which-questions-should-be-closed-a-reprise) and my somewhat-tangential (but just posted) [Modernize the close vote aging logic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/modernize-the-close-vote-aging-logic)

Comment: @Shog9 "Allow re-casting votes that age away after 14 days" Hallelujah! Praise be to the Shog!

Comment: I hope that querying the stackexchange db for question with 3+ close vote is possible, that way having a dedicated chat room for this task is a good idea. +1

Comment: "I don't recall a time when it was below 700" so you already forgot Luis Alvarado's massive reviewing? Tsk! :D

Comment: @Rinzwind Looking at my timeline, I'd just reached 3k around that time. Early days for me. :D

Comment: @SylvainPineau I don't know if there is such a mechanism. What I was hoping was: $3KUSER spots a question with 2 close votes either in review or via normal browsing. $3KUSER decides it is worth closing and casts the third vote. Now it needs 2 more, so $3KUSER drops a link in the chatroom.

Comment: We actually [*had* a chat room for this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/206), but people stopped coming and it fell dormant. If you want I can reopen it for you, but I'm not too convinced yet, the last two times I reopened it for someone it immediately fell dormant.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I present you... [The 10k tools!](http://askubuntu.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days)

Comment: @Seth not yet. Let's see if enough people volunteer their names. So far only Sylvain's interested.

Comment: @Seth Thanks, I must admit that I really forgot this tab to get such metrics

Comment: The close queue was well over 1000 a few days ago. At that point I asked http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13599/should-there-be-more-incentive-for-working-the-close-queue/13603#13603

Comment: @ElderGeek I know, I think I commented on that post. But incentive is not something we users can provide. And unfortunately so far few have volunteered names (counting Seth, you and Rinzwind.)

Comment: @muru I saw your comment and upvoted it. Raising the limit could certainly help. Re:Users and incentive. Provide, perhaps not (although I like to think that my post might have generated enough interest to encourage some to help). Request? Yes. Receive? Maybe. Based on the voting on http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13599/should-there-be-more-incentive-for-working-the-close-queue/13603#13603 there are at least 1/2 dozen who would work the queue more if there were *some* incentive.